# I can't replace the value of an array returned by mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have a notifications.find query (mongoose) that returns multiple sheets

```
Notification.find({id: id}, function(err, notifications){}
```

I need to convert the timestamp values that are returned like that

```
[                                                                                             
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("12934193c51a231b0165425a"),
    userid: '62921df1c14a2eea0efa9399',
    timestamp: 1653817696599,
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("11934193c51a231b0165425a"),
    userid: '62921df1c14a2eea0efa9399',
    timestamp: 1653817696600,
  }
]
```

I tried this

```
notifications.forEach((element, index) => {

notifications[index].timestamp = new Date(notifications[index].timestamp);

});
```

and this code

```
new Date(notifications[index].timestamp);
```

seems to work by converting the timestamp of each value, but I can't replace it in the array

I've been on this issue for several hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `forEach` use `map`

```
const newNotifications = notifications.map((element, index) => {
  return {
    ...element,
    timestamp: new Date(element.timestamp),
   }
});
```